# Should I do science of computing or systems analyst?

Tags: penetration-test, databases, server

I want to become a federal analyst of cyber crimes and I dont't know what's the right university course for me, I would like to know what's the cons and pros of choosing one or another course and why?

I would like to specialize in cyber attacks against organizations(servers,users,passwords) and so. 
Edit: Im also going to do the ELearnSecurity courses for pentesting

Thank you

Comment: I don't think either of these programs will teach you anything about security.

Comment: If you want to do anything for the government, be prepared to be writing lots and lots of wordy reports. Therefore, may I suggest a few courses in written English? ;)

Comment: Sure, Im brazilian btw hehe. @mricon

Comment: I mentioned that because is two of the needed to join the federal here ... @Rook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's less to do with which course you study, and more what you choose to concentrate on whilst at university.  However you go about getting into this field, you'll end up doing a lot of work in your own time.

It'd be useful for you to learn C and learn it well, before moving on to other programming languages, and systems architecture.

As has been mentioned, if English isn't your first language, you'll need to study that in order to study in an English speaking university, usually to IELTS level 6 standard.

To work for an English speaking governmental agency, you'll need to be fluent, although your other language(s) will count in your favour.

Comment: That's what i was expecting, i want to work for federal agency of my country ... i have a nice read/write english , enough for programming. thanks for your answer